# Cannot connect to 192.168.1.1

Tags: router, tcp

I have router TP Link n900 and I cannot connect to my admin panel of the router, I just bought it, I have internet when I am connected with cabel, but cannot open the router. My connection is :
PC -> Router -> Modem -> Internet
Chrome says that the request was rejected. How can I solve it?

Comment: Have you tried going to `https://192.168.1.1`? Some admin panels are set to work over https only.

Comment: will try.. it says 192.168.1.1 or tplinklogin.net ...

Comment: I tried... Unfortunately nothing happens.. Important is that if I ping to 192.168.1.1 it is ok.

Comment: From [TL-WDR4900 N900 Wireless Dual Band Gigabit Router](http://www.tp-link.com/Resources/document/TL-WDR4900_V1.0_User_Guide.pdf) The default
IP address
of the Router is
**192.168.0.1**

Comment: Reset router to factory defaults (there should be a little hole you would need to press for a while with a needle near the power button), then try again

Comment: What is the output from `ipconfig /all`?

Comment: Well of course I tried resetting the router + the the other ip.. without success though...

Comment: try another browser, like firefox - I have firefox, chrome, and ie - and at times one or the other doesn't let me go to 192.168.0.1 while others do

Comment: Tried .. the same ... also Firewalls are all off

Comment: Tried from another pc as well.. the same

Comment: running the Easy Install software says that it cannot find the router :(

Comment: Screenshot : http://s29.postimg.org/sh0uyj2h2/123.jpg

Comment: Connect PC to modem directly (no router), what's the output of `ipconfig /all` ? Now just connect PC to router, what does it say now ?

Comment: gateway 192.168.0.1 and ip .2

Comment: I assume you are trying 192.168.1.1 rather than 192.168.0.1 because the router is connected to a modem. According to the manual one of the things to check is that your computer's ip is in the router's range, which in this case would be 192.168.1.2-254. (Pg 20: http://www.tp-link.com/Resources/document/TL-WDR4900_V1.0_User_Guide.pdf )

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using a Windows PC, you can open a command window (also known as DOS prompt) and type "ipconfig". Look for the line with default gateway, which is the actual IP address of the router. Then you can try HTTP or HTTPS to access the router.